# Count linq statement with joins

Tags: c#, linq

I want to count via linq query.

I have list of Session objects. A list of TestRun objects where each TestRun has a SessionId. Each Session has a User And User has a Team.

I want to count the Test Runs where `TestRun.Session.User.Team == x;`

But I don't understand joins, what is the C# linq equivalent to this query?

Comment: LINQ to what? If you use an ORM like Entity Framework you don't need joins. The *ORM* will generate the JOIN statements based on the relations defined between the entities

Comment: `what is the C# linq equivilant to this query` <= to what query? [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: @GiladGreen joins in LINQ are typically a smell - why use Joins instead of relations? With a proper object model you can write `ctx.TestRuns.Count(x=>x.Session.User.Team=x);` ?

Comment: I don't have ORM, that would just be how I would write it if it was in ORM.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that really depends on the objects created. Agree that relations are better but first what are the objects and then one can suggest improvements

Comment: @user1919249 if you did, it would be considered a bad design. Whether you have an ORM or not, you have classes with relations. You should be able to write `dbCtx.TestRuns.Count(x=>x.Session.User.Team=x);` or `testRunsList.Count(x=>x.Session.User.Team=x);` ?

Comment: It's much much better to show your code rather than describe it.

Comment: @GiladGreen actually, it's typically a bug if someone asks for a join. It means that someone tried to use classes and LINQ as if they were tables and SQL. The big problem is treating objects as tables and missing the relations. Before LINQ, performing joins was hard enough that nobody thought to skimp on relations.

Comment: @GiladGreen for example, if the OP says that he has separate lists of TestRun, Session, User and Team objects, with IDs instead of strongly typed properties, wouldn't you consider it weird? Wouldn't you expect each Run to have a Session property, a Session to have a User etc?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I do agree with you. But OP should first show properly what he has. and tried. then we can improve it - code and design wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Thanks for the help guys.

```
var fullList= from session in mSessions
              join testRun in mTestRuns on session.Id equals testRun.SessionId
              where session.Value.Username.Team == "whatever"
              select new { testRun.Anything };

int count = fullList.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Code:

```
` int result=( from p in TestRun
         join q in session on p.sessionid equals q.sessionid
         join r in user on q.user equals r.userid
          where r.team==X select p ).distinct().ToList().Count();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using a database via Linq2SQL or Entity Framework, AND you've made foreign key relationships for those properties, then the JOINs are done for you automatically:

```
int result=(from p in TestRun
           where p.Session.User.Team == X
           select p).Count();
```

or

```
int result TestRun.Count(p=>p.Session.User.Team == X);
```